# how Dispose() works inside my Controller and Repository classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dispose

I am working on asp.net mvc-4 web application and entity framework 5.0. now i am confused on how Dispose is working inside my application. currently i have the following settings:-

-I have a APIRepository class which contain multiple methods that use `WebClient()` to do external API calls. and i do not define any Dispose method inside this class.

```
    public class APIRepository
        {

            public string AddTicket(string title, string technichian,string account,string site,string description,string mode,string requestor)
            {

                //code goes here

                        using (var client = new WebClient())
                        {
                        }
                   return result;
            }
//code goes here
        }
```

-I have a Repository class which contain my data access logic, and it initiate my `DbContext`, and i define a Dispose method inside this class.

```
public class Repository
{

        private MyEntities my = new MyEntities();
//code goes here...
        public void Dispose()
        {
           my.Dispose();

        }
```

-I have a Controller class, which initiate the two repository classes:-

```
[RequireHttps]

public class ServerController : Controller
{

        Repository repository = new Repository();
        APIRepository APIrepository = new APIRepository();

//code goes here
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                repository.Dispose();

            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

now i have the following questions about my current project:-

1. Based on my understanding on how Dispose works, is that when an action method calls a View, then asp.net mvc will automatically calls the Dispose method inside my current Controller class. which in turn calls the Dispose method inside my repository , which will make sure that the database connection is closed. so is my understanding valid ?
2. in my case do i need to have a Dispose method inside my APIRepository() , which as i mentioned this repository only have `WebClient()` calls to integrate with 3rd party application, and it will return object or simple string to the action method.??
3. what are the operations that need to be Disposed? as i know calling a  `my.Dispose();`  inside my repository class will make sure that the database connection is closed.. but are there other operations that need to be disposed? such as initiating a `WebClient()` or returning a JSON by my action method?
4. what are the actions other than returning a View will call the Dispose method inside my Controller class ?

Comment: I'm 100% sure you can find all answers to your question by searching in this site, maybe separated in a few questions.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are inheriting from `IDisposable`

Comment: @Jonesopolis now my ServerController class extends the Controller class. and the Controller class implements the IDisposable interface (these are done out of the box inside asp.net mvc, when i create a new Controller class), then inside the ServerController i am overriding the Dispose method.. so not sure what do u mean by "It doesn't appear that you are inheriting from IDisposable "??? thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you use dependency injection then none of the classes would be responsible for creating *or* disposing the dependencies injected into it.

Instead of this:

```
public class ServerController : Controller
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();
    APIRepository APIrepository = new APIRepository();
```

where `ServerController` creates its dependencies and is responsible for disposing of them, this:

```
public class ServerController : Controller
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;
    private readonly APIRepository _apiRepository;

    public ServerController(Repository repository, APIRepository apiRepository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _apiRepository = apiRepository;
    }
```

Now whatever creates an instance of `ServerController` is responsible for instantiating those objects and disposing of them. That "whatever" is typically your dependency injection container, like Windsor or Unity. Or even better, in ASP.NET Core it's built in and you don't need to add a separate container.

The short version: The container creates your repository, and if it needs to be disposed, it disposes it. You can even specify details about the lifetime of certain dependencies. If it's not disposable and can be reused then it's a singleton. You can create and dispose a new instance every time you need one. Or you can create a new instance that's tied to a given web request. That request uses it and then it's disposed.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, now in my case i am not using dependency injection  ,i am using Repository method class, so can you adivce how will my Dispose work? i am not sure if you are trying to say that my approach will not dispose the object ?

Comment: Repository and dependency injection aren't exclusive or contradictory. If you create the repository in your class then it can be disposed, but you have to dispose it. Using dependency injection your repository is created for you and "injected" as an argument in the constructor. The controller uses it but isn't responsible for creating or disposing it. In effect it's saying, "Not my problem, just give me what I need." If you're using a DI container then it can create the repository and then dispose it when the controller goes out of scope.

Comment: Here's a starting tutorial using Windsor. https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/basic-tutorial.md. DI was completely foreign when a co-worker introduced me to it a few years ago. It was a huge "light bulb" moment for me. It's not just that using a DI container itself solves everything, but it changed the way I thought about composing classes. It also facilitates and encourages best practice like single-responsibility classes and inversion of control. It was like a catalyst that led to a lot of other stuff making sense. Am I overselling it? It's awesome.

Comment: now i am a bit confused.. can you please adivce what is exactly wrong with my code ?? so i can understand better your answer..

Answer (score 4):

> which will make sure that the database connection is closed. so is my understanding valid ?

Your database connection is closed way before the dispose method is called.  It would be a very rare circumstance that it is not.

> in my case do i need to have a Dispose method inside my APIRepository()

Only if you are managing the disposable of objects at field level instead of a method level.

```
// The method is disposing of the object
public class NotDisposable
{
  public string GetString()
  {
    string result;
    // This is disposed by the time the method exists.
    using(var disposable new Disposable)
    {
      result = disposable.GetString()
    }
    return result;
  }
}

// This class has a field that it needs to dispose
// so it inherites from IDisposable
public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
  private bool _isDisposed;
  private readonly IDisposable _somethingToManuallyDispose;

  public Disposable()
  {
    somethingToManuallyDispose = new SomethingImplementsIDisposable();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)  
  {
    if (disposing && !_isDisposed)
    {
      _isDisposed = true;
      // Dispose Managed Resources
      if (_somethingToManuallyDispose != null)
      {
        _somethingToManuallyDispose.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> but are there other operations that need to be disposed?

Example above, where you do not Dispose of an object in the method.

> what are the actions other than returning a View will call the Dispose method inside my Controller class

That sentence doesn't even make sense.  Returning a View does not call Dispose.  The MVC/API Pipeline Disposes of the controller after the response is sent to the client, and only if it implements `IDisposable`.

Please consider reading [MSDN - Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MSDN - Implementing a Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MSDN - Using Objects That Implement IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bwa4xa9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but i have these questions on our reply 1) what do u exactly mean by "Only if you are managing the disposable of objects at field level instead of a method level."? second question in my current implementation the Servercontroller class extends the Controller ,and the Controller implements the IDisposable interface (this is done out of the box by asp.net mvc), and in my case i am overriding the Dispose method inside the ServerController, so how will Dispose work in my case ? i am not sure if my approach is correct or wrongs ?