# During multiple http request I get status code 500 from the asp net web api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project that is built using asp net web API (framework). I have 3 tiers architecture. DAL layer has a unit of work and a generic repository. BLL has services. API is for controllers.
The problems is arising when I am trying to do multiple get requests from the angular project. I would appreciate it if somebody tells me where I am wrong.
Here is the code

Repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly GameShopContext _context;

        public Repository(GameShopContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetQuery(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<T> set = filter == null ? _context.Set<T>().Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                : _context.Set<T>().Where(filter).Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
            {
                set = includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Aggregate(set, (current, includeProperty)
                        => current.Include(includeProperty));
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                set = orderBy(set);
            }

            return set;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "",
            bool asNoTracking = false)
        {
            var query = GetQuery(filter, orderBy, includeProperties);

            if (asNoTracking)
            {
                var noTrackingResult = await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

                return noTrackingResult;
            }

            var trackingResult = await query.ToListAsync();
            return trackingResult;
        }
}
```

Unit of work

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly GameShopContext _context;
        private readonly Lazy<IRepository<Comment>> _commentRepository;
        private readonly Lazy<IRepository<Game>> _gameRepository;
        private readonly Lazy<IRepository<Genre>> _genreRepository;
        private readonly Lazy<IRepository<PlatformType>> _platformTypeRepository;
        private readonly Lazy<IRepository<Publisher>> _publisherReposiroty;
        private bool _disposed = false;

        public UnitOfWork(
            GameShopContext context,
            Lazy<IRepository<Comment>> commentRepository,
            Lazy<IRepository<Game>> gameRepository,
            Lazy<IRepository<Genre>> genreRepository,
            Lazy<IRepository<PlatformType>> platformTypeRepository,
            Lazy<IRepository<Publisher>> publisherReposiroty)
        {
            _context = context;
            _commentRepository = commentRepository;
            _gameRepository = gameRepository;
            _genreRepository = genreRepository;
            _platformTypeRepository = platformTypeRepository;
            _publisherReposiroty = publisherReposiroty;
        }

        public IRepository<Comment> CommentRepository => _commentRepository.Value;

        public IRepository<Game> GameRepository => _gameRepository.Value;

        public IRepository<Genre> GenreRepository => _genreRepository.Value;

        public IRepository<PlatformType> PlatformTypeRepository => _platformTypeRepository.Value;

        public IRepository<Publisher> PublisherRepository => _publisherReposiroty.Value;

        public async Task SaveAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

The services of entities that I am trying to get are similar to each other so

```
public class GenreService : IGenreService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly ILoggerManager _loggerManager;

        public GenreService(
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            IMapper mapper,
            ILoggerManager loggerManager)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _loggerManager = loggerManager;
        }
public async Task<IEnumerable<GenreReadListDTO>> GetAsync()
        {
            var genres = await _unitOfWork.GenreRepository.GetAsync();

            var genresDTO = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<GenreReadListDTO>>(genres);

            _loggerManager.LogInfo(
                $"Genres were returned successfully in array size of {genresDTO.Count()}");
            return genresDTO;
        }
```

Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/genres")]
    public class GenreController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IGenreService _genreService;

        public GenreController(
            IGenreService genreService)
        {
            _genreService = genreService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getAll")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllGenresAsync()
        {
            var result = await _genreService.GetAsync();
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

I am using Unity di

```
container.RegisterType<GameShopContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IRepository<Genre>, Repository<Genre>>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository<PlatformType>, Repository<PlatformType>>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository<Publisher>, Repository<Publisher>>();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
container.RegisterType<IGenreService, GenreService>();
container.RegisterType<IPlatformTypeService, PlatformTypeService>();
container.RegisterType<IPublisherService, PublisherService>();
```

This is Angular code

```
this.genreService.getAllGenres().subscribe((genres: Genre[]) => {
            this.gameGenres = genres;
        });
this.platformTypeService.getAllPlatformTypes().subscribe((data: PlatformType[]) => {
            this.platformTypes = data;
        });
this.publisherService.getAllPublishers().subscribe((data: Publisher[]) => {
            this.publishers = data;
        });
public getAllGenres(): Observable<Genre[]> {
        return this.http.get<Genre[]>(`${this.apiUrl}getAll`);
    }
```

Please tell me if I need to provide more code

The only thing that works is async ngOnInit() that is not good to have.

Comment: Why do you force your own (probably inferior - but mine would be, too) implementation of UoW and Generic Repo on top of entity framework?

Comment: maybe try TransientLifetimeManager instead of new HierarchicalLifetimeManager() but i do not use unity i am just guessing.

Comment: You may not closing the connection after each request.  So second connection is failing because server is not allowing multiple connections.  Try disposing the controller on the server so you start clean before each connection.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213450/how-dispose-works-inside-my-controller-and-repository-classes?force_isolation=true

Comment: As a side note: I could imagine the optional AsNoTracking() will become troublesome.